# Custom pages on all multisite network, to NOT show in wp-admin at all

Tags: multisite, pages

I have a Wordpress Multisite that I would like to create additional pages for all of the sites in my network. These pages will not show up in the list of pages that are editable by the site admin in their wp-admin area, but instead will be static pages using css that is not the same as the theme of the actual site itself. They will not have access to the traditional Wordpress admin, and will only get the information from these pages as a custom admin panel.

My question is, how do I create a plugin that generates these pages that do not exist inside the traditional page flow and are hard coded to always exist on every one of the sites.

Comment: What have you tried? What *exact* problem are you having? Do you have any relevant code that you can [add to your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/147804/edit) to clarify the situation for us?

Comment: I don't have a problem persay. I'm trying to extend wordpress to have a custom admin area for the site owners in a multisite.